# React omit source maps while keep Sentry recognise them

Tags: create-react-app, sentry, source-maps

**Context** 
We're trying to omit any source maps in our production build using react create app while keep uploading it to sentry.

To my understand it's supposed to work, however Sentry refuses to recognise the uploaded source maps.

How we're using it:

**Source build commands** 
Simply (1) creating a `build` using `react scripts` including source maps. (2) uploading them to Sentry, and (3) removing all source maps from the generated `build`.

```
...
"release": "(export REACT_APP_SENTRY_RELEASE=woodhouse@$(git rev-parse --short HEAD); react-scripts build && node scripts/sentry.js)",
"postrelease": "find ./build -name '*.map' -delete",
...
```

**Scripts/sentry.js** 
Script uploading it to Sentry using Git commit hash as release.

```
const SentryCli = require('@sentry/cli');

async function createReleaseAndUpload() {
  ...
  const release = process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_RELEASE;
  const cli = new SentryCli();

  try {
    ...
    await cli.releases.new(release);
    await cli.releases.uploadSourceMaps(release, {
      include: ['build/static/js'],
      urlPrefix: '~/static/js',
      rewrite: false,
    });
    await cli.releases.finalize(release);
  }
  ...
}

createReleaseAndUpload();
```

**Init Sentry** 
Initialising Sentry SDK; using the same git commit hash.

```
...
const SENTRY_RELEASE = process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_RELEASE;
...
    if (SENTRY_RELEASE) {
        /**
         * The release identifier used when uploading respective source maps. Specify
         * this value to allow Sentry to resolve the correct source maps when
         * processing events.
         */
        sentryOptions.release = `${SENTRY_RELEASE}`;
    }

    Sentry.init(sentryOptions);
...
```

**Sentry source map release** 
As can be seen, Sentry does have the uploaded source maps
[image]

**Sentry Issue**
And as can be seen in this issue, which is linked to the same release; it's not recognising the source maps..
[image]

**Question** 
What are we doing wrong here? Our aim is to keep using the react scripts but if needed we can `eject` the project and try using [sentry's webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/webpack-plugin) using `devTool: hidden-source-map` (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) and `deleteAfterCompile` [option](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin/issues/99). But at this moment I am not even confident this will even work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend deleting everything you have set up in regards to Sentry sourcemaps and running the Sentry source map wizard: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/#uploading-source-maps

Comment: Let me try to use the webpack plugin but like I tried to explain; our goal is to avoid having any source maps in our production build while do uploading them to sentry. And as can be seen in the post; the sentry release did actually have the source maps. But still wasn't recognising it.

So I almost assume Sentry actually needs the maps to also be in the production build in order to map the minified code... But will try the webpack plugin next

Comment: You can delete (ie. not deploy) your sourcemaps directly after uploading them to Sentry. The webpack webpack plugin even has an option to automatically do this for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/webpack-plugin#sourcemapsfilestodeleteafterupload

Comment: That's what we originally had as an approach - as described in the question; however Sentry didnt recognise the source maps...

Comment: @JimVercoelen I stumbled over this post having exactly the same question. My combo is CRA, Heroku and Sentry. Did you manage to figure this out in the end?